# Selectively revert or checkout changes to a file in Git?

Tags: git

Is there a command that allows you to partially undo the changes to a file (or files) in the working directory?

Suppose you have edited a file a lot but you realize that you want to undo some of the changes back to the committed state, but not the other changes.

I'm envisioning an option for `git checkout` that works a lot like `git add -p`, i.e. it goes through the file hunk by hunk and asks if you want to keep it or not.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You could use

```
git add -p <path>
```

to stage the chunks that you want to keep in a particular file, then

```
git checkout -- <path>
```

to discard the working tree changes that you didn't want to keep, by checking out the staged version of the file.

Finally, you can use

```
git reset -- <path>
```

to revert the staged version of the file to the most recent committed version of the file to leave you with your changes unstaged (if you don't want to commit them).

Comment: For this simple use case, which every other version control system just calls "revert", why is the Git command so obscure?

Comment: @Jan Do other version control systems' `revert` command allow you to select which changes within a file are reverted? Genuinely asking, as I only have experience with CVS and Git. In Git, `git checkout -- path/to/file` is a single command that reverts all changes in that file, but this is not the same as above.

Comment: There's also `git checkout --patch` and `git reset --patch` which work like `git add --patch` in latest git.

Comment: @Rudie, the `--` usually indicate the end of options parsing, and that any arguments that come after it are to be interpreted literally. This means that you wouldn't have to add `./` before any filename that starts with a minus sign, if the filename comes after `--`.

Comment: when i use `git checkout --patch` the diff appears to be backwards. The minus symbols are ADDING text to my working copy, and the plus symbols are REMOVING lines from my working copy.

Answer (score 121):

With git version >= 1.7.1 I can

```
git checkout -p dir/filename
```

or to iterate through "all changed hunks in all files"

```
git checkout -p
```

I am not sure when this feature was introduced.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can also do `git reset -p` to selectively unstage changes from the staging area/index. I also don't know off the top of my head in which version of Git that this was introduced.

Comment: This is the correct answer, why it's not been accepted.

Comment: @wukong because this answer has been posted 2 years after the question. At this moment (2009), Charles's answer was the best solution

Answer (score 9):

`git checkout $file` reverts the state of the file `$file` to the last committed state. I think you can use `git checkout SHA-1 -- $file` to revert the file to the commit identified by SHA-1.

Comment: yeah, not exactly what I want, since I want to keep some of the changes I have made in the file and revert the others

Answer (score 2):

How many commits do you need to go back and select from? If it's just one, maybe take a branch just before it, checkout the file you committed and then use `git add -p` to add it how you wanted it. Then you can go back to where you were and checkout the file from your temp branch.

that is:

```
git checkout -b temp troublesome-commit^
git checkout troublesome-commit -- path/to/file
git add -p path/to/file
git commit -c troublesome-commit
git checkout @{-1}
git checkout temp -- path/to/file
git commit path/to/file
git branch -D temp
```

Other alternatives include going back and editing the commit with `git rebase -i` (marking the commit as `edit`, then doing a `git reset HEAD^` and redoing the commit when dropped back into the shell).

If the changes you need to select from are spread over a series of commits, it may be better to extract them as patches (or a patch covering all of them) and hand-edit the patch, taking out the changes you want to keep, and feeding the residual into `git apply --reverse`.

Comment: I'm not actually wanting to revert anything that is committed, I want to undo changes that are only in my working copy