# Git - How do I revert my local files to the last commit i made?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I host my files on bitbucket and normally commit changes every now and then.

Since my last commit, I have made some mistakes in my code.

(These mistakes have been saved in their respective local files and I haven't added it to the local git repo just yet using git add.)

I would like to revert back to my last commit with the working code. I am currently working on a branch off the master.

What command should I use for this?

Comment: Some previous threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004237/git-revert-to-previous-commit-status http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965639/rollback-to-last-git-commit ...

Comment: @eis nope, the talk is about reverting not yet commited changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to selectively revert or checkout changes in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771897/how-to-selectively-revert-or-checkout-changes-in-git)

Comment: @om-nom-nom so are those links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you discard unstaged changes in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard` will revert all files to `HEAD`.
I prefer this to `git checkout -- .` but that's just a matter of preference.

Comment: I tried this git reset --hard ab53ga3s and it reverted my files to the ab53ga3s commit

Answer (score 1):

For a file: `git checkout -- filename` also `git checkout -- directory/`  will do this for the entire directory and of course `git checkout -- .` for the entire repository.